# View doesn't refresh after RedirectToAction is done

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redirecttoaction

Here is my problem:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddData(CandidateViewModel viewModel)  
{
    var newCandidateId = 0;  
    newCandidateId = this._serviceClient.AddCandidate(viewModel);  
    return  RedirectToAction("DisplayCandidate",new {id=newCandidateId});  
}

public ActionResult DisplayCandidate(int id)
{
    var candidateViewModel= this._serviceClient.GetCandidate(id);
    return View(candidateViewModel);
}
```

After filling the form viwemodel sends to server. After data were stored, flow is redirected to DisplayCandidate  action and it goes there but page didn't refresh. I don't understand why! Help, please.

Comment: Are you posting via AJAX? Show your client-side code.

Comment: yes. AJAX: if (DataIsValid())
        {
            $.ajax({
            url: "/Candidate/AddData",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: ko.toJSON(addCandidateCommonInfoViewModel),
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'json'
        });
        }

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because you are using Ajax Post

```
public ActionResult AddData(CandidateViewModel viewModel)  
{
    var newCandidateId = 0;  
    newCandidateId = this._serviceClient.AddCandidate(viewModel); 
    string ReturnURL = "/DisplayCandidate/"+newCandidateId;
    return JSON(ReturnURL);  
}
```

and in your Ajax Post Method:

```
Onsuccess(function(retURL){ window.location(retURL); })
```

This will take to the new Action and that Action will return View.

Comment: change your controller AddData method to get.

Comment: replace `windows.location(retURL)` with `location.replace(retURL)`

also never use manual url contructing, us `Url.Action("DisplayCandidate", new { id = newCandidateId })`

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Ajax, return a script results to execute the navigation

instead of

```
return  RedirectToAction("DisplayCandidate",new {id=newCandidateId});
```

try

```
 var viewName = "/Path/ViewName";
 var id = 1;
 var urlNavigate = string.Format("location.href='{0}?id={1}'", viewName, id);
 return new JavaScriptResult() { Script = urlNavigate };
```