# Page is not refreshed by calling RedirectToAction

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

In the **View** I have a linked button and there is java scripts to collect information from view and then post to the corresponding action '**GroupDeny**'

```
@Html.ActionLink("Deny Selected", "GroupDeny", null, new { @class = "denySelectedLink" })

    @section Scripts {
      @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")

      <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).on('click', '.denySelectedLink', function (e) {
          //Cancel original submission
          e.preventDefault();

          var identifiers = new Array();

          //build the identifiers . . .

          var jsonArg = JSON.stringify(identifiers);
          $.post('/LicenseAssignment/GroupDeny?licensePermissionIdentifiers=' + encodeURIComponent(jsonArg));
        });        

      </script>
```

Then in the controller, the **GroupDeny** will update the DB and then 
call *RedirecToAction* in order to refresh the view

```
public class LicenseAssignmentController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GroupDeny(string licensePermissionIdentifiers)
    {
       // changes the DB

       return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

  // GET: 
  public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
  {
    var model = get data from DB

    return View(model);
  }
```

Everything seems work as expected, The **Index** will be called after the *RedirectToAction("Index")* is executed, and the model is update to date their when I watch it during debugging, the only problem is that the page is not refreshed at all, that is to say the view still keep unchanged, but after I refresh the page manually (press F5), the data will be updated with the values from DB

Comment: AJAX will not follow the 302 redirect. If you want to redirect use a standard from post instead of AJAX. Or you'll need to trap the response and navigate with JavaScript.

Comment: @Jasen Thanks for your response, but I am new to the web dev, would you please provide more detailed info?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use AJAX when we *don't* want to navigate away from the page. Your `$.post()` is an AJAX request.

Since you want navigation add a form to your page

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("GroupDeny", "LicenseAssignment", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <input type="hidden" value=""
        name="licensePermissionIdentifiers"
        id="licensePermissionIdentifiers" />
}
```

Now submitting this form will navigate

```
$(document).on('click', '.denySelectedLink', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();  // prevent link navigation

    var identifiers = new Array();

    //build the identifiers . . 

    // populate the form values
    $("#licensePermissionIdentifiers").val(identifiers);

    $("form").submit();
});
```

The `RedirectToAction()` returns to the browser a `302 Redirect` to `LicenseAssignment/Index` then you hit the Index action.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using Ajax you will have to redirect on the return of your `$.post` call and change your `GroupDeny` to  a `JsonResult`.

Something like this maybe:

JS

```
$.post('/LicenseAssignment/GroupDeny?licensePermissionIdentifiers=' + encodeURIComponent(jsonArg), function(data){
    if(data.Success){
        //redirect
        window.location.reload();
    }else{
        //handle error
    }
});
```

Controller Action

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GroupDeny(string licensePermissionIdentifiers)
{
   // changes the DB

   return Json(new { Success = true });
}
```

Comment: `window.location.reload();` was the key for me. The suggestions from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11955161/view-doesnt-refresh-after-redirecttoaction-is-done of `window.location(returnURL)` and `window.location.replace(returnURL)` didn't work for me.